# In Elasticsearch [0.90.7 & 1.0.0RC1] how can I troubleshoot a missing analyzer issue?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have been following this example here for setting up soundex search:  http://blog.jessitron.com/2012/04/configuring-soundex-in-elasticsearch.html

I have installed the plugin fine locally, and the analyzer works as I expect it to.  However when I deploy to a separate server, I'm getting different behavior - an error when I try to put the analyzer in a mapping.

I have tried this with fresh installs of both 0.90.7 & 1.0.0RC1.  In both cases it is the same - the plugin works fine on my local machine, but not on the remote one.

### Relevant bit from my elasticsearch.yml file:

```
index :
    analysis :
        analyzer :
            search_soundex :
                type : custom
                tokenizer : standard
                filter : [standard, lowercase, soundex_filter]
        filter :
            soundex_filter :
                type : phonetic
                encoder : soundex
                replace : true
```

### What I'm sending as my map:

```
  PUT customer_requests_140113/
{ "mappings": {
        "customer_request" : {
        "properties" : {
            -- SNIP --
            "Contacts" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "ContactMethods" : {
                        "properties" : {
                            "Type" : {
                                "type" : "string"
                            },
                            "Value" : {
                                "type" : "string"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "FullName" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                        ,"index":"analyzed"
                        ,"analyzer": "search_soundex"
                    },
                    "StopNumber" : {
                        "type" : "string"
                    }
                }
            },
            -- SNIP --
        }
    }
```

### The response from ElasticSearch:

```
{
   "error": "MapperParsingException[mapping [customer_request]]; nested: MapperParsingException[Analyzer [search_soundex] not found for field [FullName]]; ",
   "status": 400
}
```

### The error I am getting in my logs:

```
[2014-02-06 11:15:13,128][DEBUG][action.admin.indices.create] [xxxxxxx] [customer_requests_140113] failed to create
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: mapping [customer_request]
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$2.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:312)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.InternalClusterService$UpdateTask.run(InternalClusterService.java:298)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:135)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Analyzer [search_soundex] not found for field [FullName]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.TypeParsers.parseField(TypeParsers.java:100)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.StringFieldMapper$TypeParser.parse(StringFieldMapper.java:150)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:263)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(ObjectMapper.java:219)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parseProperties(ObjectMapper.java:263)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper$TypeParser.parse(ObjectMapper.java:219)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapperParser.parse(DocumentMapperParser.java:176)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.parse(MapperService.java:314)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.merge(MapperService.java:193)
    at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$2.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:309)
    ... 5 more
```

### The startup log:

```
[2014-02-06 11:13:10,372][INFO ][node                     ] [xxxxxxx] version[0.90.7], pid[2152], build[36897d0/2013-11-13T12:06:54Z]
[2014-02-06 11:13:10,372][INFO ][node                     ] [xxxxxxx] initializing ...
[2014-02-06 11:13:10,403][INFO ][plugins                  ] [xxxxxxx] loaded [analysis-phonetic], sites [head]
[2014-02-06 11:13:16,877][INFO ][node                     ] [xxxxxxx] initialized
[2014-02-06 11:13:16,877][INFO ][node                     ] [xxxxxxx] starting ...
[2014-02-06 11:13:17,158][INFO ][transport                ] [xxxxxxx] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9300]}, publish_address {inet[/10.117.11.60:9300]}
[2014-02-06 11:13:20,341][INFO ][cluster.service          ] [xxxxxxx] new_master [JBVWEBD42B][phzrhkfXQtGNX8Wv93xOpw][inet[/10.117.11.60:9300]], reason: zen-disco-join (elected_as_master)
[2014-02-06 11:13:20,372][INFO ][discovery                ] [xxxxxxx] xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
[2014-02-06 11:13:20,372][WARN ][discovery.zen.ping.multicast] [xxxxxxx] received ping response ping_response{target [[xxxxxxx][xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx][inet[/10.117.11.61:9300]]], master [[xxxxxxx][xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx][inet[/10.117.11.61:9300]]], cluster_name[xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx]} with no matching id [1]
[2014-02-06 11:13:20,434][INFO ][http                     ] [xxxxxxx] bound_address {inet[/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9200]}, publish_address {inet[/10.117.11.60:9200]}
[2014-02-06 11:13:20,434][INFO ][node                     ] [xxxxxxx] started
[2014-02-06 11:13:20,450][INFO ][gateway                  ] [xxxxxxx] recovered [0] indices into cluster_state
```

### Output from /_nodes/plugin:

```
{
    ok: true
    cluster_name: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    nodes: {
        xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx: {
            name: xxxxxxxxxxx
            transport_address: inet[/10.117.11.60:9300]
            hostname: xxxxxxx
            version: 0.90.7
            http_address: inet[/10.117.11.60:9200]
            plugins: [
                {
                    name: analysis-phonetic
                    description: Phonetic analysis support
                    jvm: true
                    site: false
                }
                {
                    name: head
                    description: No description found for head.
                    url: /_plugin/head/
                    jvm: false
                    site: true
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

### My thoughts so far:

I can see that the phonetic analyzer plugin is getting loaded from the startup script.  I also know from `/_nodes/plugin` that it's aware of it after loading.  But when I try to use it in a custom analyzer, it seems to blow up.  This baffles me, because the same setup seems to work on my local machine!

Comment: when you check the index settings (get settings api), do you get back your custom analyzers and filters?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm still stumped by this!  When I call _settings I get {} (nothing).